# is there a way to check matches in strings in php like the "like" in mysql?

Tags: php

For example i have this string `"this is a testing string"`, and I want to test weather the word "string" is in there.
How would I do that in PHP?

```
$theMessage = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['message']));

$s1='binuang';
$s2='ilad';
$s3='fraud';
$s4='fake';
$s5='ayaw mo ug tuo';
$s6='pangilad';
$s7='bot2';
$s8='bot-bot';
$s9='botbot';
$s10='di tinuod';
$s11='di ni tinuod';

$t1=strpos($theMessage, $s1);
$t2=strpos($theMessage, $s2);
$t3=strpos($theMessage, $s3);
$t4=strpos($theMessage, $s4);
$t5=strpos($theMessage, $s5);
$t6=strpos($theMessage, $s6);
$t7=strpos($theMessage, $s7);
$t8=strpos($theMessage, $s8);
$t9=strpos($theMessage, $s9);
$t10=strpos($theMessage, $s10);
$t11=strpos($theMessage, $s11);

if($t1===true || $t2===true || $t3===true || $t4===true || $t5===true || $t6===true || $t7===true || $t8===true || $t9===true || $t10===true || $t11===true)
{

$sql2=mysql_query("UPDATE property SET valid='1' where p_id='$q'");

}
```

Answer (score 4):

if it's a direct match, you can do something like:

```
$stringToTest="this is a testing string";
$findMe="string";


if(strpos($stringToTest,$findMe)!==FALSE){
//something
}
```

however, because of the case where the string position could be zero, you need to do the !==FALSE method to accurately address all cases

Comment: hey. its like this, i am using this strpos for my web application that has comment. so example whenever a user has bad words in his comment, flag column in my table in database would have the value 1. flag are all initialized to zero by default. so what i did is store all bad words i thot into $s1,$s2,$s3.... and so on. and compare all these when a comment is submitted using strpos. but its not working. is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match();` or `strpos();`...

`strpos();` would be easier, because it won't involve regular expressions, but huh, experiment and see what suits you best!

Okay, lets begin...
1) You would earn a lot by putting all those "bad" words inside an array, like:

```
$badwords = array('badword1', 'badword2', 'badwords3'); // and so on...
```

2) Let's run through all the badwords and check for their position in message, with a loop:

```
$found = 0; // just a simple counter, to populate if a bad word is found..
foreach($badwords as $word){ // for each "bad word" from array, used in loop as "$word"
    if(strpos($theMessage, $word) !== 'false'){ // if we've found the word...
        $found++; // ...plus one for found
    }
}
```

3) The query part... We check if bad words have been found, and if yes, we show error, otherwise continue with query:

```
if($found > 0){ // self explanatory...
    echo 'Error, bad words found, you shall not pass!';
}else{
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `property` SET `valid` = '1' WHERE `p_id` = '{$q}';"); // {$q} == $q, just formatting preference.
}
```

4) All together, just for fun and the length of answer:

```
$theMessage = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
$badwords = array('badword1', 'badword2', 'badwords3'); // and so on...

$found = 0; // just a simple counter, to populate if a bad word is found..
foreach($badwords as $word){ // for each "bad word" from array, used in loop as "$word"
    if(strpos($theMessage, $word) !== 'false'){ // if we've found the word...
        $found++; // ...plus one for found
    }
}

if($found > 0){ // self explanatory...
    echo 'Error, bad words found, you shall not pass!';
}else{
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `property` SET `valid` = '1' WHERE `p_id` = '{$q}';"); // {$q} == $q, just formatting preference.
}
```

Have fun!

P.S. I have no idea if this works, can't test at the moment, but I think it should.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: hey. its like this, i am using this strpos for my web application that has comment. so example whenever a user has bad words in his comment, flag column in my table in database would have the value 1. flag are all initialized to zero by default. so what i did is store all bad words i thot into $s1,$s2,$s3.... and so on. and compare all these when a comment is submitted using strpos. but its not working. is my approach wrong?

Comment: @user628961, please post your whole script for that, there can be many reasons why it's not working. And, there is no right or wrong approach as long as you get your desired result, with some exceptions ofcourse. So, yeah, please post the script which is processing those words on submit. It would save a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

```
$haystack = "this is a testing string.";
$needle = "string";
$found = strstr($haystack, $needle);

if($found!==FALSE)
   echo "I found it!";
```